# What are the technical requirements and reasonable master format for an iphone icon?

Tags: iphone, icons

I'm looking to commission an icon for an iphone app, and would like to provide the designers with the technical requirements. Also, as this may also be used as a logo for the website I'd like to be have a format that I can reuse and scale myself.

What technical requirements should I give to the designer and does apple have a publically linkable description of these? Is it simply 57x57 and 150x150 png or is there more to it?

Also, what is a reasonable, preferably open, scalable master format to request? I don't have photoshop and don't want to get it just for this.

Answer (score 4):

The [iPhone Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) document about custom icons and images explains it in detail

Answer (score 0):

My icon designers typically provide me with a vector file format version of my icon (usually an Illustrator file), a 512x512px TIFF file (which is submitted to Apple for use in the AppStore), and a 57x57px PNG (which is used as the actual application icon).

Also, If you want to get rid of the pre-rendered glossy bit you'll see on most iPhone apps' icons, go search for UIPrerenderedIcon, which is a flag you can set in your app's Info.plist file.

You don't need to go get Photoshop or Illustrator just for this, but you should have a 'master' file that you can keep in perpetuity in case you ever need another graphics designer to make modifications to the original icon.